# NGUI android Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ngui

I'm developing a game in Unity3D and the interface I'm using ngui, but I have the following problem, my scene consists of three cameras; UIRoot only for the ngui the CamObject to a 3D scenery and MainCamera that gathered the two:

[image]

the scene I want is that the below , when I run the Unity3D works fine , however when I move on to the phone to camera UI Root not appear with the sprite when I take the camera CamObject, the camera UI Root is visible on mobile:

[image]

on mobile:
[image]

Depth of cameras: 
MainCamera depth: 0,
UI Root depth: 2 (UIPanel Scrpit depth: 2) 
CamObject depth: 1
Some help?

Comment: What is the UICamera's culling mask?

Comment: you right, I miss that... thank!